# Tools that can help in code checking in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there any good tools or Eclipse Plugins that would scan my Android Project and identify possible 'Memory leaks', susceptible code for 'Force closes' and other general code standards of Java and/or Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One good tool is the "LINT" Tool Available in Eclipse + Android-SDK.

> http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

Another good find was "FindBugs" that locates Java Bugs and suggests enhancements.

> ```
> http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/
> http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse/
> ```

Is there any other tool that you'd suggest ?

Comment: Were you really interested in any answers to your question? You answered the same minute that you asked the question, which seems basically impossible for the answer above without having it prepared in another editor...

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer the question but does offer an alternative.

In my opinion, Intellij IDEA is better than Eclipse in almost every way.  Its' code inspectors in combination with Android Lint and Findbugs is powerful.  The way IDEA finds, reports and visualises possible bugs, "code smells" and suggestions for refactoring is superb.  I'm not aware of any IDE that does the job as well.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution within Eclipse. I don't want to be looking at a new IDE right now. Thanks for the suggestion for an alternative IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Besides [android-lint](/questions/tagged/android-lint), which is already available in your installation of the ADT and finds Android specific issues, I recommend both [Findbugs and CodePro Analytix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720413/findbugs-vs-google-codepro-analytix-eclipse-plugins) for standard Java code checks.

Answer (score 2):

A force close is just any uncaught exception in you code, such as a `NullPointerException`. You can debug these issues as they occur by reading the stack trace output to logcat.

For memory analysis I suggest you start by watching [Memory management for Android Apps](http://youtu.be/_CruQY55HOk?hd=1) (a session from Google I/O 2011) and read the companion blog post [Memory Analysis for Android Applications](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html). They provide some good suggestions for strategies and tools to debug memory leaks and other issues.